# liclipse: can't change string font/color in pydev editor preferences

Tags: liclipse

I switched from an older version of Eclipse to LiClipse 3.1.0 (linux).  I can get the pydev editor fonts just like I'm used to, except there is no selection for "string" under window>preferences>editor>appearance-color-style in Liclipse.

There was such a selection in my old Eclipse preferences.

Is there a way to change the string color/font in pydev editor?

Answer (score 0):

LiClipse colors are usually managed by Eclipse Color Theme.

i.e.: to change the colors, go to the `Preferences > General > Appearance > Color Theme`, then, you can either select a different theme or edit the `string` color under an existing theme.

Still, if you don't want to use a theme and are using the `Default`, go to `Preferences > PyDev > Editor` and change the color there.